# How to safely delete core dump info?

Tags: systemd, systemd-coredump

I am on Ubuntu server 20.04 and I have `atop` installed. Within my understanding, `atop` will keep record of certain information when an application core dumps.

I am running low on disk space and this directly seems to be holding multiple gigs of data, as can be seen below:

```
358M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.aide.0.935d95ab5fbc4d4f80db94b63058c49b.187328.1667955502000000000000.lz4
358M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.aide.0.9e5d6cc7a461420899546075fe5bb612.111352.1668043764000000000000.lz4
358M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.aide.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.39004.1667694813000000000000.lz4
357M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.aide.0.eed96640ad184ff89f7170f3f8958261.146152.1667872541000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.2926a2184416449892007750d60c454c.1131.1667775435000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.345c5ad2902c429884f21d5a0c43475b.1176.1668083856000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.388f3d696e394952b99ef5efb5c64e51.1183.1667811948000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.935d95ab5fbc4d4f80db94b63058c49b.1170.1667912923000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.9e5d6cc7a461420899546075fe5bb612.1203.1667997414000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.c1898a755cbf4e639fb148be42ef9fcc.1127.1667775722000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.1132.1667702354000000000000.lz4
3.6M    /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.mongod.140.eed96640ad184ff89f7170f3f8958261.1181.1667824797000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.22078.1667683319000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.24398.1667683284000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.24692.1667683283000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.24695.1667683285000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.26270.1667683485000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.26271.1667683486000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.26743.1667683786000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.26746.1667683786000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.27028.1667683819000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.27185.1667684087000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.27186.1667684087000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.27682.1667684388000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.27689.1667684388000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.28223.1667684687000000000000.lz4
49M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.28224.1667684688000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.28640.1667684987000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.28641.1667684988000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29042.1667685289000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29043.1667685290000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29529.1667685590000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29530.1667685590000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29813.1667685664000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.29814.1667685606000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31510.1667685843000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31513.1667685843000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31569.1667685892000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31570.1667685894000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31980.1667686193000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.31981.1667686193000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.32399.1667686494000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.32400.1667686494000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.32814.1667686794000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.32815.1667686794000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.33270.1667687095000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.33271.1667687095000000000000.lz4
49M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.39005.1667687467000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.39007.1667687467000000000000.lz4
27M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.39078.1667687467000000000000.lz4
49M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.47653.1667687716000000000000.lz4
50M /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.\x2fusr\x2fshare\x2fwebm.0.ec134b8b03d64426b2a418ba57492b56.47663.1667687716000000000000.lz4
```

Is it safe to set up a `cron` job to periodically clear out the `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` directory, until I have a chance to troubleshoot the reason the core dumps are happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cleanup all dumped core stored by `systemd-coredump`, you can run (as root):

```
systemd-tmpfiles --clean
```

To an answer your direct question, yes, the coredump files are safe to delete.

See here for more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220420/cleaning-up-coredumpctl-list